# Google Maps returns null

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a Google Maps Activity. suddently it is shutting down because getMap() (java null pointer exeption) doesn't seem to work. I reinstalled some older apks that worked fine and but yet these are shutting down to. So it has to be something on the device or so, what can be the reason?

```
private GoogleMap googleMap;   
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
try {
        if(googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }
```

Here is the xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.mareike.cityexplorer/de.mareike.cityexplorer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.l.a.ce.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.eg.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.ef.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.aq.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.ft.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.l.onTransact(SourceFile:167)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.addMarker(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(Unknown Source)
        at de.mareike.cityexplorer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:88)
```

Comment: Post you manifest. Have you included everything that's required?

Comment: Post also your logcat.

Comment: Are you calling MapView's onCreate before getMap()?

Comment: I added some code to my question to show how I call it

Comment: No I always tested with the same device and version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMap()), the `getMap()` method is deprecated and you need to use `getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback)` instead.

Sample code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 10));

    }
}
```

and the `activity_main.xml`:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          tools:context=".MapsActivity"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

For more details, please refer official doc [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start).

Comment: But I don't use a FragmentActivity but a ActionBarActivity. How can I implement OnMapReadyCallback there?

Comment: The same way, just change `FragmentActivity` to `ActionBarActivity`.  Because `ActionBarActivity` is also deprecated, you can use `AppCompatActivity` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check your layout activity_main should contains fragment having id **map**

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: yes it has. the strange thing is that I also testet old apk files that once worked and now suddently doesn't so I didn't change anything in the code... I'm getting mad :(

Comment: post your logcat or stacktrace . This will tell about why this error is occurring.

Comment: Its occuring when the first marker is set because of java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: is default google map application in your phone working fine?

Comment: if not then update Google Play services on android phone [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en)

Comment: I startet the regular google maps app and saw that the search history was disabled. I enabled it and suddently it worked!! What does this have to do with getting the map?